# Sending SMS to Contacts using Twilio

Tags: batch

I need to send sms to contacts using twilio on a weekly basis.I have the code for sending sms but I need to call this class using batch apex on a weekly basis.Does anyone have code for the same?

Comment: can you share your code.

Comment: I need to call this class from batch apex to send sms to all the cntacts

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create class which implements Batchable and Schedulable interface, and in Schedulable execute method call Database.executeBatch with the same class initialization parameter, and in Batchable execute method just call the logic you need.

You class also needs to implement AllowsCallout interface to make sure you can make callout to twilio from inside of batchable execute method.

Then schedule this class manually or using code for weekly basis.

Please mark my answer as accepted if you agree it solves your problem.

Comment: how to get the contact id in the Database.QueryLocator start method since the  contact id will not be available then

Comment: you need to have determine how can should identify for which contacts you need to sent sms. If you don't have any requirements then just select all contacts